# vim command for cscope does not under file

Tags: vim, centos

Previously I was on Ubuntu with vim/cscope.
Now I changed to CentOS due to team requirement, which also has vim and cscope:

- vim version: 8.0
- cscope version: 15.6

Then I went to c project, and `cscope -R`. I was in the cursed-based GUI, the search is ok with that GUI.
The issue is when I was in one file, and tried to use vim command like `:cs find g xxxx`.
It seems no reaction at all, the cursor just went back to where it was and no search result came up. That works good in previous Ubuntu

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: I find that cscope/ctags are never perfect. I end up using vim's grep instead. Not a direct cscope fix, but a workaround for the problem (the grep results can show up in the quickfix window just like cscope results).

Comment: What cscope-related options do you have in your Vim config?